# Implementing smooth scrolling with two frames in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a two frame webpage where i have the tabs in the right frame and the contents in the left frame. I already set anchor tags to link the content when the nav tabs are clicked in the right frame. I need to implement smooth scrolling for that. I can do that in the same page but i dont know how to do with two frames. Please help me with this.

Comment: Frames are the worst possible practise as far as I know. I'm just trying to say that I wouldnt encourage usage of frames.

Comment: Use IFRAMEs instead if you have to have content in separate files. Then you could arrange the smooth scrolling from the main container file.

Comment: @EricG He could be using marquee's ;-)

Comment: what you tried ? see some content for that we can help you.

Comment: @jtheman iFrames? Really? :S Just as bad no..? :/ You suggest using a hash then?

Comment: may I know the procedure to do using iframes?. I have the content in the left frame and the nav tab in the right. So shall I put the content in iframe rather than a separate file?..

Comment: Bah I recall I saw a "website" (helpfile) in our company that used frames, and if it was in my possession I would even like to refactor it even in my spare time! Iframes and frames are always troublesome (limited), and even more if you also would like to support touchdevices.

Comment: @EricG I totally agree with you but I can't know what reason the user has for keeping content in separate files and loading with ajax might be too complicated for him...

Comment: @jtheman I can imagine that but I think that we as a community should always guide people into "best practises" from which they may profit now and/or in the future. I get your assumption since he's already asking <this> ^ question, but okay. We should ask why he keeps them seperate ;)

Comment: @EricG True, I'll think of that!

Comment: Thank you all. I got it done. But not with frames. I am new to web development and so a bit confused with the frames. I removed it and did the same by just separating the same with two divs.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could steal the code I made for a mock company which does exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/Rovanion/JC

I cloned it onto my web server for your viewing pleasure: http://rovanion.se/jc/

I can add that this is not a straight forward issue to solve, especially if you want hash addresses to actually work at the same time as the scrolling. Because then you have to suppress the built in navigation of the browser.

But in short you can look at my code and write your own or use my code under the license I just added to it.

Comment: Remember to do accept an answer to the question which you've asked once you've found a solution that works. It's good etiquette.

Comment: Seems like you found it. Best of luck. And in the future. Try to submit more specific qeustions presenting the specific issues you are having in code. This was a borderline "write this code for me" question which is normally just thrown out of Stackoverflow.